# Does SCP between 2 machines copy file to the current machine in the background?

Tags: file-transfer, scp

If I am copying file from remotemachine1 to remotemachine2 and I am currently at remotemachine3, will the file from remotemachine1 in background first copy to remotemachine3 and then to remotemachine2?

Update: I am using Linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about *`scp` OpenSSH secure file copy* then the answer is in [`man 1 scp`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp.1#3):

> `-3`
>   Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host. Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts. […]

So the answer is no, unless you used `-3`. The option is useful if the two end hosts cannot communicate directly. Examples: [link 1](https://superuser.com/q/315358/432690), [link 2](https://superuser.com/q/418768/432690).

According to the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.7) the option was added in OpenSSH 5.7/5.7p1 (2011-01-24).