# How can I execute a command on a remote server through scp?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unix, scp

When using ssh to access raspberry pi running balenaos, `ssh -t -p 22222 root@device-ip "balena-engine exec -it <container_name> /bin/sh"` grants me access to a specific container inside of the balenaos host.

Now I need to use scp to transfer files to this specific container. What would be the correct syntax that results in scp connecting to this container in the same way the aforementioned ssh command does?

Comment: Is `scp` available in the container?

Comment: "Now I need to use scp to transfer files to this specific container. " That's not the preferred way of using a container. And unless you can ssh directly into the container, you cannot directly scp into it. So you need to use the balena-engine methods to copy files (in Docker, that's `docker cp`; no idea if balena also has that - read the man page).

Comment: You *may* be able to pipe a `.tar` stream, e.g. `tar cf - /path/to/local/files | ssh -p 22222 root@device-ip "balena-engine exec -it <container_name> tar xf - --directory=/destination/folder --preserve-permissions"` (completely untested)

Answer (score 3):

#### Preliminary note

This answer had been written before OpenSSH made `scp` use SFTP by default (2022-04-08, see the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0)). The answer investigates and relies on the behavior of *legacy* `scp`. See "History, SCP and SFTP" in [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1733992/432690).

---

#### Analysis

To `scp` something to a container you need to be able to run `scp` in the container. You don't need an SSH server in the container though.

**If you cannot run `scp` in the container then this answer won't help you.**

When you `scp` to or from a remote location, your local `scp` (the client) runs `ssh` under the hood to connect to the remote location and run a specific command there. The command is passed as a single string and interpreted by the remote user's shell, like any command passed via `ssh`.

In case of `scp` the command is… `scp`; with special options though. The options are undocumented (you won't find them in `man 1 scp`), they turn `scp` into a server.

If you manage to alter the string passed to the remote shell then you will be able to run `scp` server in the container instead of in the host (assuming you actually can run `scp` in the container).

You can alter the string thanks to the `-S` option of `scp`:

> `-S program`
> Name of program to use for the encrypted connection. The program must understand `ssh(1)` options.

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#S))</sup>

With `-S` you can make `scp` run a custom executable instead of `ssh`. The executable should then run `ssh` and pass the altered string to it.

---

#### What happens under the hood

(You can skip this section. It's here for educational purposes.)

Let's see what exactly `scp` invokes and what the undocumented options are. Create a local file named `spy` and make it executable (`chmod +x spy`). This is the code to put in `spy`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
printf '<%s> ' "$@" >/dev/tty
printf '\n' >/dev/tty
```

Now invoke `scp` with the `spy` instead of `ssh`. Use a dummy name for a server, our `spy` won't connect to anything.

- Downloading. Local command:

  ```
  scp -S ./spy dummy:/remote/path /local/path
  ```

  Output from `spy`:

  ```
  <-x> <-oForwardAgent=no> <-oPermitLocalCommand=no> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <--> <dummy> <scp -f /remote/path>
  ```
- Uploading. Local command:

  ```
  scp -S ./spy /local/path dummy:/remote/path
  ```

  Output from `spy`:

  ```
  <-x> <-oForwardAgent=no> <-oPermitLocalCommand=no> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <--> <dummy> <scp -t /remote/path>
  ```
- Uploading more than one file. Local command:

  ```
  scp -S ./spy /local/path1 ./path2 dummy:/remote/path
  ```

  Output from `spy`:

  ```
  <-x> <-oForwardAgent=no> <-oPermitLocalCommand=no> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <--> <dummy> <scp -d -t /remote/path>
  ```

This means without `spy` and in a shell (that is going to remove quotes) the commands would look like the following, respectively:

```
ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -- dummy 'scp -f /remote/path'
ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -- dummy 'scp -t /remote/path'
ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -- dummy 'scp -d -t /remote/path'
```

We can see the special options for the remote `scp` are `-f`, `-t` and `-d`. You can also find them [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_08.htm).

---

#### Altering remote command

As said and shown, `scp` client uses `ssh` to run `scp` server on the remote side. Proper command is passed to `ssh` as a single string. It's always `scp …` (where `…` includes special options). It's the last argument for `ssh`.

To run `scp` in the container instead of in the host, you need to turn this `scp …` string into `balena-engine exec -it <container_name> scp …`. But this is somewhat flawed. Note a local command like this:

```
scp 'server:/remote/path/*' ./
```

can be used to download many files. The wildcard (`*`) is supposed to work in a remote shell. Indeed, the remote command will be `scp … /remote/path/*` and the remote shell will expand `/remote/path/*`. However if you turn the remote command into:

```
balena-engine exec -it <container_name> scp … /remote/path/*
```

then the shell running on the host will expand `/remote/path/*`. This is wrong, `/remote/path/` may not even exist in the host; and if it exists, its content may be different than what `scp` will find in the container. You most likely want `/remote/path/*` to be expanded in the container. For this you need a shell in the container. You need to turn `scp …` into:

```
balena-engine exec -it <container_name> /bin/sh 'scp …'
```

This is how the last argument for `ssh` should look like. Single-quotes hiding behind `…` are troublesome. [There are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104052/10765659) to deal with them.

---

#### Altering remote command – the script

Let's build a custom executable (script) and tell `scp` to use it instead of `ssh`. Our executable will call `ssh` with the last command line argument modified.

It will be good not to hardcode `<container_name>`. `scp -S` takes the name of executable, we cannot pass an option this way. We can pass something in the environment though.

Create a local file named `balena-helper` and make it executable (`chmod +x balena-helper`). This is the code to put in the file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}" "balena-engine exec -it ${container@Q} /bin/sh ${!#@Q}"
exec ssh "$@"
```

The code uses few non-portable features of Bash. It wouldn't work in plain `sh`.

---

#### Usage

In general use `balena-helper` like this:

```
container=container_name scp -S /local/path/to/balena-helper …
```

where `…` denotes all options and operands you would normally place after `scp` (e.g. `-P 22222 /local/file root@device-ip:/destination/`; note it's `-P 22222` while with `ssh` it was `-p 22222`).

It's possible to create a wrapper script over `scp` that would use `balena-helper` iff `container` is in the environment (it would behave like regular `scp` otherwise). I wouldn't do this though. If I were you and was going to work with `scp` and a specific container, I would create a temporary alias:

```
alias scp='container=container_name scp -S /local/path/to/balena-helper'
```

And then I would use `scp` in this particular local shell in a straightforward way, e.g.:

```
scp -P 22222 /local/file root@device-ip:/destination/
```

where `/destination/` is valid in the container. Finally I would `unalias scp`.

---

#### Notes

- `scp` can copy from local to local. In this case `-S` is ignored.
- `scp` can copy between two remote locations (with or without [`-3`](https://superuser.com/a/1515716/432690)). `balena-helper` is not designed to be used in this mode.
- When rebuilding the last argument, `balena-helper` quotes (`@Q`) few strings so they cannot inject code when the whole command string is interpreted by the shell on the remote host. The `scp …` command that gets to the shell in the container *can* run additional code; but this is what `scp` can normally do (and fixing it was not my intention). E.g. this command makes my Debian 10 beep:

  ```
  scp kamil@debianserver:"; beep" ./
  ```

  It only works because I can run `beep` via `ssh` anyway. `scp` doesn't give me (or anyone else) more possibilities that `ssh` does. Still, if I forget that some argument I provide for a local `scp` will become (a part of) shell *code* on the remote side, I may inadvertently run some code on the machine (or container) where `scp` is about to run in server mode. And so may you.
- [This already mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104052/10765659) notices `@Q` in Bash is not perfect. See [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29824428/10765659) for alternative. I chose `@Q` to keep `balena-helper` relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

## RUN SCRIPT IN SERVER BY SSH

**write your script in local machine and run it in your server with your args (var1,var2 .):**

```
var1="test1"  
var2="test2"  
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  USER@HOST "bash -s" < $HOME/locale.sh $var1 $var2
```