# Can't SCP from Windows remote to MacOS

Tags: windows, macos, scp

I have ran into an issue where I cannot use `scp` from my Mac laptop to copy files from my Windows PC.

The command I am running on MacOS:
`scp user@pcname:\Users\Will\treemnger\ Documents/treemnger`*

It returns the same output as `scp --help`.

**'user' and 'pcname' are placeholders*

Comment: I'm not giving a full answer because I don't know pitfalls of using `scp` on Windows, but locally on Mac there are problems: (1) Unquoted backslashes escape characters that immediately follow, including the space. No backslash gets to `scp`. Single-quote. (2) Unquoted asterisk can trigger filename generation. // My guess is you're passing one argument to `scp`, where you need at least two. Don't you want `scp -r`? If the asterisk is supposed to be in the second argument then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `scp -r 'user@pcname:\Users\Will\treemnger\' 'Documents/treemnger/'` makes more sense. But because of how `scp` works (see the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634882)) a *shell command* will be invoked on the remote side. The path will be digested again. If the shell there is `sh`-like then it will treat the backslashes again as escape characters. If it's `cmd.exe`-like then it's different. `scp` on the remote side may interpret on its own. It may expect pathnames with backslashes or with slashes. That's why I cannot give you a command that will work with Windows for sure.

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes like this: `scp user@pcname:/Users/Will/treemnger/ Documents/treemnger/`? That said, the command will fail because, as already commented above, the copies the contents of a folder, which requires a `-r` switch in `scp` like this: `scp -r`.