# SCP is not working when running it on linux to Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh, scp

We have OpenSsh installed and running on remote windows server. When I connect to it through Remote Desktop and run `scp` on command prompt it gives all the available options for scp commnad.

but when I am trying to scp from my linux machine to it like `scp myuser@windows-machine:test.txt .` it's giving me the below error

```
'scp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I can do ssh using the same user credential and after doing ssh if i run the scp there still it gives the same error.

Can anybody please help if I am missing some configuration on remote windows machine ?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like where `scp.exe` is isn't in the `PATH` environment variable set for the ssh session. Not sure how/where to set it if you are using the build Microsoft ships though.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your question does not seem consistent. You say you run</s>

ReEditted thanks to Kamil's comment

```
homedir@linuxhost$ scp myuser@windows-machine:test.txt .
```

<s>Yet your error message is literally generated by a windows shell.

That doesn't seem right, unless...... You are running PowerShell as your shell on your linux system</s>

On my windows system with OpenSSH-server installed there are 2 instances of scp.exe:

```
homedir@linuxhost ssh myuser@windows-machine where scp
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\scp.exe
```

Strangely the actual executable used by sshd is the one in "Program Files". Perhaps (re)installing the OpenSSH-client feature will fix your problem.

Comment: -1. `scp` works by `ssh`-ing to the server and running `scp` *as a shell command there*. Compare the beginning of [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690), also my comments under [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/652091/108618). If the remote shell cannot find `scp` then it will generate an error message. The error message from a Windows shell does not mean the OP uses PowerShell on the client.

Comment: Have you seen the linked answer? `scp` on the client runs something like `ssh … user@server 'scp …'` and the remote shell is involved in running `scp` on the server.