# Cannot send file from local machine to the server using SCP despite being able to login via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine, scp

I am trying to send file from my local machine (Ubuntu) to Oracle VM (Oracle Linux).

Command I tried is below, but it doesn’t work.

I can connect to the server fine using SSH.

```
scp -r -i /full_path_to_the_private_key/priv-key.key root@my_ip:/tmp/file.zip opc@server_ip:/tmp
root@my_ip's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@my_ip's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@my_ip's password: 
root@my_ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

To refer to the "file from your local machine", use `/tmp/file.zip` instead of `root@my_ip:/tmp/file.zip`.

---

#### Analysis

> I am trying to send file from my local machine (Ubuntu) to Oracle VM (Oracle Linux).
>
> […]
>
> ```
> scp […] root@my_ip:/tmp/file.zip opc@server_ip:/tmp
> ```

To handle an address like `root@my_ip:…` `scp` runs `ssh` to run `scp` (see "what happens under the hood" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690); but note it does not analyze the case of two remote addresses).

I understand `my_ip` refers to your local machine, yet `root@my_ip:…` is formally not a local path. Your `scp` tries to `ssh` to `root@my_ip` and run `scp` there; this is the connection that fails. If it succeeded, the other `scp` would read `/tmp/file.zip`.

---

#### Solution

`scp` is perfectly capable of reading a local file without `ssh`ing from local to local; just give it a local path:

```
scp -i /full_path_to_the_private_key/priv-key.key /tmp/file.zip opc@server_ip:/tmp
```

Here `/tmp/file.zip` is the local path. (Note you don't need `-r` when transferring a regular file I assume `file.zip` is.)

The above is similar to the command `scp` in your try would run after logging in via SSH to `root@my_ip`, if you managed to log in. Our solution is to run the command directly. The difference is our `scp` runs as the user you currently are, while your try requests `scp` running as root. I don't know if your current user is root; it may not be and the difference may or may not matter. Keep reading.

---

#### About root

Specifying `root@my_ip:/tmp/file.zip` only makes sense as a (cumbersome) way of accessing `/tmp/file.zip` as root, in case you cannot access the file as the user you currently are. There are better ways to access the file as root.

A straightforward way is with `sudo`:

```
sudo scp … /tmp/file.zip opc@server_ip:/tmp
```

however it will run the entire `scp` as root. This is more than accessing a file as root, because now *everything* `scp` does will (or at least can) be done as root. Considering the fact the `scp` command you tried (if everything worked) would run another `scp` after logging in to (formally remote) `root@my_ip` and it would do this *as root*, running (some) `scp` as root is what you tried anyway. In other words `sudo scp …` is (almost) equivalent to what would happen if you were able to connect to `root@my_ip`.

Still, using `sudo` (or another way) to access the file as root is required only if you cannot access the file as your regular user. If you (as your current user) can simply access the file then you should directly invoke `scp` and tell it to read the file by its local path `/tmp/file.zip`; this is exactly the solution given in the previous section of this answer.