# SSH config: is there a way to distinguish between ssh and scp commands?

Tags: ssh, scp

I manage SSH connections to remote machines using a special `ProxyCommand` in my ssh_config file. Suffice to say it's structured like this:

```
Host my-target
    IdentityFile /path/to/temporary-key
    ProxyCommand /path/to/custom-script %n %r %p /path/to/temporary-key
```

As you can see, when I enter `ssh me@my-target`, SSH will read this file and execute the `custom-script`, passing it the hostname, user, (default) port, and a path to the private key it will attempt to use to authenticate to the server (which the custom script will generate in real time). **This works just fine**.

However, I would like for the `custom-script` to behave differently depending on whether it was invoked via `ssh` vs. `scp`. As far as I'm aware, [there is no ssh_config token that stores this](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config), but it seems like it should be possible in theory.

Is there a way to pass this information to my `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: [The XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) You might get better advice if you [edit] your question to describe what you'd like `custom-script` to do differently for scp connections.

Comment: `scp` simply runs `ssh` with arguments (see "what happens under the hood" [here](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690)). There is no token because from the point of view of `ssh` the situation is no different from a shell (or whatever) running `ssh` with arguments. Unless your `scp` uses SFTP (see [*OpenSSH SCP deprecation in RHEL 9: What you need to know*](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/openssh-scp-deprecation-rhel-9-what-you-need-know)).