# How to scp java innerclass with '$1' in its name

Tags: scp

**Files**

```
sample$1.class
sample.class
scp_test.sh
```

**scp_test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=('sample.class' 'sample$1.class')

for dd in "${TARGET[@]}"
do
  FILENAME=`basename ${dd}`
  scp ${FILENAME} remote:/tmp/${dd}
done
```

When the shell is run, `sample$1.class` is overwritten on `sample.class` on remote server,
leaving only  `sample.class`.

```
$ ./scp_test.sh
sample.class               100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
sample$1.class             100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
$ ssh remote 'ls -l /tmp/'
total 01 
sample.class
```

It only happens when it's copied by `scp`. Local copy using `cp` doesn't behave like this.

---

*EDIT
Since I use Bash version under 4.3(4.2.46), I can't use `${dd@Q}`.
I fixed the problem by using quote combiniation `'"${dd}"'` instead of plain `${dd}`.

Comment: so my take is that dd has the value of "sample$1.class" and $1 is being expanded to an empty string ("") during your scp invocation. even though you defined the filename as a literal using single-quotes, that only means something when you are putting the value into the array. when you pull it out to use it, the literal-ness of it is lost, and the variable gets expanded. you need to make sure you are treating everything you pull from the array as literal. I'd probably start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445313/1624069 and try `TARGET=('sample.class' 'sample\$1.class')`

Comment: @FrankThomas That's what I initially did but it's kinda messed up. If I change the target to `sample\$1.class` it searches for litteral name `sample\$1.class` and says `sample\$1.class: No such file or directory`. I had to chang the name of target file to `sample\$1.class` and when it was scp'd it became `sample$1.class`. I felt like it's a workaround solution.

Comment: That's a known issue with how scp works (until it *finally* got rewritten to use SFTP last month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

This answer is mainly about traditional `scp`, i.e. legacy `scp` using the SCP protocol. Modern `scp` from OpenSSH uses SFTP by default and when I'm writing this the transition is less than two months old; so it's quite fresh. I can tell your `scp` uses SCP, because if it used SFTP, you wouldn't encounter the issue in question. Solving such issues was one of the reasons SCP was replaced by SFTP.

From the [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0):

> OpenSSH 9.0 was released on 2022-04-08. […]
>
> […]
>
> This release switches `scp(1)` from using the legacy scp/rcp protocol
> to using the SFTP protocol by default.
>
> Legacy scp/rcp performs wildcard expansion of remote filenames (e.g.
> `scp host:* .`) through the remote shell. This has the side effect of
> requiring double quoting of shell meta-characters in file names
> included on `scp(1)` command-lines, otherwise they could be interpreted
> as shell commands on the remote side.

---

#### Potential issues independent from `scp`

First of all: [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Your example names may be safe even if unquoted, still writing robust code is a virtue. IMO it's easier to always quote than to think hard each time if you can get away without quoting. Your code with properly quoted variables will look like this (note I don't attempt to solve the issue with `scp` yet, this will be done in a moment):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

target=('sample.class' 'sample$1.class')

for dd in "${target[@]}"
do
  filename="$(basename "${dd}")"
  scp -- "${filename}" "remote:/tmp/${dd}"
done
```

(I also fixed [names all in capitals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618), introduced [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) in case you ever add a filename starting with a dash to `target`. I think `basename` is a no-op in this particular case, but I assume you have a reason for it.)

If your `scp` used SFTP then the above code would work (and frankly I think your original code would also work with such `scp`, but only because the names you used are "safe" when unquoted).

---

#### The issue with `scp`

Unfortunately the legacy `scp` embeds the remote pathname in a shell code that is meant to be interpreted by a remote shell (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690)). The remote shell will interpret characters like quotes, `$`, `[` etc., unless they are escaped or quoted when they get to the remote shell. This means locally you need to *additionally* quote with the remote shell in mind. You need to quote for the local shell *and* for the remote shell. This is what the citation means by "requiring double quoting of shell meta-characters in file names".

---

#### Solution

Bash can help. `"${dd@Q}"` will expand `dd` and escape or quote the result, so *after an additional level of interpretation* (performed by the remote shell in your case) the result will be a single word you would expect (like `"$dd"` expanded locally). The following line is a fix for the legacy `scp`:

```
scp -- "${filename}" "remote:/tmp/${dd@Q}"
```

The whole script will be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

target=('sample.class' 'sample$1.class')

for dd in "${target[@]}"
do
  filename="$(basename "${dd}")"
  scp -- "${filename}" "remote:/tmp/${dd@Q}"
done
```

The solution is not portable, it won't work in pure `sh`. The shebang in your script is `#!/bin/bash` from the beginning, so I guess you don't mind code that only works in Bash.

---

#### Final notes

- The first snippet (without `${dd@Q}`) is right for `scp` using SFTP (i.e. the new one). The second snippet (with `${dd@Q}`) is right for `scp` using SCP (i.e. the legacy `scp`). There is no simple universal code. The new `scp` supports `-O` that makes it behave like the legacy `scp`, but if you use a legacy `scp` with `-O` then it will fail because it will find the option invalid. Either way you need to know if your `scp` is new or old, and adjust your shell code accordingly. For now your `scp` is old (and hence the issue in the first place), but if you update it, it may be replaced by a new one. The already linked [changelog](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) notices the incompatibility:

  > This creates one area of potential incompatibility: `scp(1)` when using
  > the SFTP protocol no longer requires this finicky and brittle quoting,
  > and attempts to use it may cause transfers to fail. We consider the
  > removal of the need for double-quoting shell characters in file names
  > to be a benefit and do not intend to introduce bug-compatibility for
  > legacy scp/rcp in `scp(1)` when using the SFTP protocol.
- Side "issue", a friendly advice. Naming your scripts like `scp_test.sh` is not a good habit. For your `scp_test.sh` the interpreter is already `bash`, not `sh`. Your original code needs `bash` and doesn't work in pure `sh` (because of the array). Are you going to rename to `scp_test.bash`? What if you ported the script to Python? OK, I don't think you will do this to the *very* script in question, but in general you might. Then every tool that calls `scp_test.sh` would need to be fixed and call `scp_test.py` instead.

  Name the script `scp_test`. You can tell if `scp_test` is executable by examining its permissions. If you want to know what it is, invoke `file scp_test`. Now you can rewrite the script in whatever language you want, or even compile a binary, and you (or anyone/anything) can still run it as `scp_test`.

Comment: I can't use `@Q`  operator because I use GNU bash, version 4.2.46. sad days.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using quote combiniation `'"${dd}"'`

Comment: @Lunartist I think `'"${dd}"'` cannot work, because `${dd}` [is single-quoted](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690). Unless you mean `"remote:/tmp/'"${dd}"'"`, but here `${dd}` is locally unquoted, quite wrong. Less wrong would be `"remote:/tmp/'${dd}'"`. It's at least *locally* OK, still it would fail or misbehave on the remote side if the expansion of `$dd` contained at least one single-quote. Seeing `$dd` locally double-quoted or not, I can imagine unfortunate (or deliberately crafted) local filenames that can execute code on the remote side.

Comment: You're right but it should work for `$` sign. Should I try using `eval` and then single quote it?