# scp : "unexpected filename: . ", but I don't see a "."

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I want to `scp` a `.sh` script to `/dev/shm` but it gives me

```
error: unexpected filename: .
```

I don't even see where there would be a lone `.` in either the script or the directory.

The full command was:

```
scp -r /opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh jan@10.10.87.42: /dev/shm
```

(it's from a newbie hacking CTF-type game). I tried adding `$(pwd)` as suggested in other threads but to no avail.

Comment: What's the goal here? copy `linpeas.sh` to the remote host? If so, the format is `${user}@${host}:${path}`, so remove that space before `/dev/shm`! ("_no path_" is interpreted as "_here_" or `.`).

Comment: Oh man, that's it! Thank youuuu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scp` like `cp` supports copying from multiple sources to a single target directory. In your command

> ```
> scp -r /opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh jan@10.10.87.42: /dev/shm
> ```

`/opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh` and `jan@10.10.87.42:` are sources, `/dev/shm` is a (local) target. For local copying `scp` falls back to `cp`. Your command is roughly equivalent to:

```
cp -r /opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh /dev/shm
scp -r jan@10.10.87.42: /dev/shm
```

and `jan@10.10.87.42:` in the latter is equivalent to `jan@10.10.87.42:.` and means "`.` (the current working directory) after `ssh`-ing to `jan@10.10.87.42`".

While totally local `cp -r . /dev/shm` (or even `scp -r . /dev/shm`) may work, `scp` refuses to download a remote [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) named `.`. (I mean the legacy `scp` which uses SCP, not SFTP. See "preliminary note" in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690). It appears your `scp` uses SCP. My tests indicate `scp` using SFTP can download `.` from a server.)

---

With that being said, I suspect maybe you don't want local `/dev/shm` as the target directory. Maybe you want:

```
scp -r /opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh jan@10.10.87.42:/dev/shm
```

where `jan@10.10.87.42:/dev/shm` is a remote target, it means `/dev/shm` on `10.10.87.42`. The above command will upload local `linpeas.sh` to *remote* `/dev/shm`. You don't really need `-r`, unless `linpeas.sh` is a directory.

Comment: Thanks so much for that detailed explanation. Learned a lot today! It was the bloody space in the end ... But your explanation definitely made me appreciate and think more deeply about unexpected behaviors. There really is a reason why I should be more careful with commands and learn why it does certain things. "The computer does what you tell it, not what you want it to do" I was reminded of that right now.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/shm` is the shared-memory of Linux, that can be addressed as a disk.
It is not an SSH server.

You should be using:

```
scp -r /opt/PEAS/linPEAS/linpeas.sh /dev/shm
```

But I'm not sure that this is what you wish to do.
The size is limited, and the data would be lost after a reboot.

See for example
[What Is /dev/shm And Its Practical Usage](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html).

Comment: Looks like I don't understand the concept of shared memory even after reading that article. The guy in the tutorial did it like this. Though on second glance I see that he didn't have a space between jan@10.10.87.42: and /dev/shm. Would that change the behavior? I probably need to read up on fundamentals before messing around in these CTFs. Thanks though!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).